# Display image selected for uploading before upload not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display an image after selecting from the hard drive before it is sent to the server (upload). I found a small code on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PrNWY/13/) website, I copy pasted it but it's not working (it is on the demo page). I can select an image and it's name is displayed to the right of the Choose File button, but neither the image nor the size is displayed. I am pulling my hairs out.

Whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  <!-- Using margin:auto will not work in IE8, unless a !DOCTYPE is declared. -->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link href="design3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">

// Handle file while select a new file
$('#file').change(function () {
    $('#img_size').val((this.files[0].size) / 1000000);
    handleFiles(this.files);
});


// handle files
function handleFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;
        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }
        var img = document.getElementById('fake_img');
       /* img.src = file;
        img.onload = function () {
        }; */
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (aImg) {
            return function (e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}



function drawAd() 
{
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
}

</script>

</head>
<body> 

    <input type="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="text" id="img_size" />
    <img src="" id="fake_img" />

    <button type="button" onclick="drawAd()">Refresh</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Tested in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console?

Comment: Also, are you importing jQuery, which that code relies upon?

Comment: I am new to jQuery. I have this in the head block: <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> and this .js file is in the same directory as my webpage.

Comment: OK, well the first thing to do is check the error console.  Also, you should wrap that code up as a "ready" handler: put `$(function() {` before the first line of code, and `});` after the last line.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? what's the error console? And why would I put those around the code? Btw. I can run javascript functions, if that matters (calling onclick="gotopage() in a button form object results in a new window opening a webpage given by me:
`function gotopage() 
{
 window.open('http://www.google.com');
}`

Comment: The error console is a feature of a browser where errors from JavaScript code are reported; exactly what it looks like depends on the browser you're using, but F12 usually starts the debugging tools. That code I wrote in the other comment will "wrap" the code you posted such that it will be run only after the browser has completed your document.  As it is, it will run *before* any of the document has been seen, so the code will have no effect.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, because now that I think of it it's probably a fundamental problem.

Comment: I added the whole code. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing the rest of your code (the HTML for the form), but *probably* what's happening is that your code is running before the browser has seen and parsed your HTML.

Wrap your code as a jQuery "ready" handler:

```
$(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

and see if that helps. This line:

```
$('#file').change(function () {
```

sets up an event handler for the "change" event on the file input.  When that runs, if there's no element that the browser knows about with "file" as its "id", then you'll get no error but nothing will happen.  By delaying that code until the browser has seen your whole document (which is what that jQuery "ready" wrapper does), you make it such that the "file" input can be found.

Comment: It looks like that opening and closing part was the solution. Thank you so much! Btw, what should I look for in the error console? Should it log me any problems?